# How to run background tasks in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to design an application that does two different tasks in parallel 
each task start executing when the user presses  a button in the activity "so I have three Activities two of them should  do some tasks and the third one should collect the result".

*When the user presses the button on the activity it will invoke a thread and then will Load the next Activity*

In the third activity I have a button "I called it Send Button " that should stay inactive or disabled until all threads finish their work so at that moment it will be enabled and this activity contains plain text to show the result from these two threads and when the user presses this button it will send the information in the plain text to  a web site.

My questions are : how can I run Threads in a different activity and send their result to another one? and how can I make that "Send Button" disabled until all threads finish their work.

I tried to make a while loop using a global variable in  the onCreate method in the Third activity  but it crashes the application and the activity didn't start up

Comment: Only one activity can be active at any given time. Why can't you run the different threads from the activity where you have the button?

Comment: You should take a look at  the `asyncTask` class.

Comment: @Joni,,You are right but I need to use ImageProcessing methods in the first activity while the user enters his information in the second one , and in background ,a method will be invoked "in a thread"  to determine his location

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to do a long running background task:

- Using a thread which does your background work, with an singelton to access the results
- Using a services which does the calculations

Depending on your actual use case the service is the first choice.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Activity *only* when you need user interaction to your application. Else you can invoke both the threads using AsyncTask for your jobs(If you want the system to handle the worker threads for you. And unless you do not do any config changes on the fly -> performance hit).

Please keep in mind that, you should use AsyncTask only when the background jobs run for dew seconds. If you have a long running job, then use a service with a custom thread.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **AsyncTask**. AsyncTask  is one Class which is used to perform background processes without having threads. You can easily check the process is completed or not. Check this [Tutorial](http://startandroiddevelopment.blogspot.in/2014/06/asynctask-in-android.html). This can help you to understand how to run background process using an AsyncTask.

Comment: "without having threads" is wrong. "AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler..." https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask